# Run http sample in Jmeter for 1 minute and generate only 200 requests

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Please help me to achieve this type of load testing in Jmeter,i have configured Scheduler configuration but it is not running as per Duration as 60 minutes with in 10 seconds it is completing the requests and my Vusers -5 and Loop Count-50

Please help how to prepare this type of scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

If you need 200 requests - decrease loops count to 40 (5 users x 40 loops == 200 total requests)

Also consider using [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) or [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) to limit the throughput to 200 requests per minute (something like 3.3  requests per second).

Comment: But how can i run Run for 1 Minute?

Comment: Can you please help how to configure Request per seconds start and end rps in case i want to reach upto 200 requests in 60 seconds?

Comment: Please proviode options how to run for 1 minute exactly